# How to solve for the velocity?

Tags: equation-solving

Given the equation:

$m \dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = m g_{e} - \beta v^{2} $ the velocity evaluates to $ v(t) = \sqrt{\dfrac{m g_{e}}{\beta}} \tanh \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{\beta g_{e}}}}$. In Mathematica

```
Solve[{m x''[t] == m g - β x'[t]^2, x'[0] == 0}, x'[t]]
```

Doesn't return anything. What should the input be to get the analytic solution $ v(t) = \sqrt{\dfrac{m g_{e}}{\beta}} \tanh \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{\dfrac{m}{\beta g_{e}}}}$?

Comment: It appears that you are new to the Wolfram Language. One possibility to consider when experiencing difficulty with a function is that you are using the wrong function. Near the bottom of each documentation page there is a section with the heading of "See Also". It will help you explore and learn the language.

Answer (score 3):

This will return what you want:

```
Simplify[DSolve[{m v'[t] == m g - β v[t]^2, v[0] == 0}, v[t], t], m > 0 && g > 0 && β > 0]
```

Comment: Or using the original notation, `x'[t] /. DSolve[{m x''[t] == m g - β x'[t]^2, x'[0] == 0}, x, t]`